# Final Else statement will not work inside do...while loop. C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, do-while

Okay so this is my first post ever on here so take it easy on me! ^.^
I'm very new to C# and programming in general, an I'm trying to fight my way through a lab for my college intro to programming course.

The purpose of the lab is as follows:

- Prompt the user to enter the diameter of a pizza in inches
- Pizza diameters can be entered as real numbers. Ensure that the
  user input is numeric using the TryParse() method
- When the user does enter ‘0’ for diameter, immediately end the program without any
  further processing, message or prompt
- Check that the diameter entered is within the range of 12” to 36” inclusive
- Display an error message and re-prompt for a valid entry if entry is invalid
- If the entry is valid, calculate pizza area and determine maximum number of slices produced
- Diameters of 12” up to and including 20” can only be cut in eight slices.
- Diameters larger than 20” up to and including 24” can be cut into a maximum of 12 slices.
- Diameters larger than 24” up to and including 30” can be cut into a maximum of 16 slices.
- Diameters larger than 30” can be cut into a maximum of 24 slices.
- Create an output formatted to show the list of all possible cutting configurations of the pizza and the number of slices and slice area for each configuration
- Continue prompting user for an entry of a pizza diameter, still offering 0 to end the program
- Display the results in a list for each entered diameter
- Clear the console using Console.Clear() Prior to displaying a new list each time

I am having particular trouble trying to figure out why my final "else" statement will not work. It is the exact same as I had it in a previous lab so the code isn't wrong for what I need, but when the entry is not between 12-36" inclusive my if-else statement is supposed to jump down and display my "Error Entry" message stating its not within the range. The rest of my code works but I cannot figure out why it will not display my else statement when the entry is incorrect!

My code currently, with some minor changes that I have been playing with to try and get it to work:

```
                do
                {
                    if (double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out pizzaDiameter) == false)       //
                    {
                        Console.Write("\n\tENTRY ERROR\nDiameter must be a numerical number!");                 
                        Console.Write("\n\nPlease enter the diameter of your pizza (0 to end program): ");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (pizzaDiameter >= 12 && pizzaDiameter <= 36)
                        {
                            pizzaRadius = pizzaDiameter / 2;                        //Calculating the radius of the pizza by dividing diameter by 2
                            wholePizzaArea = Math.Pow(pizzaRadius, 2) * Math.PI;    //Determining the whole area of the pizza by multiplying radius^2 by pi

                            if (pizzaDiameter > 30)
                            { 
                                Console.Write("Cut in " + SMALL_PIZZA + " slices results in a slice area of " + Math.Round(wholePizzaArea / SMALL_PIZZA, 2) + "\" per slice");
                                Console.Write("\nCut in " + MEDIUM_PIZZA + " slices results in a slice area of " + Math.Round(wholePizzaArea / MEDIUM_PIZZA, 2) + "\" per slice");
                                Console.Write("\nCut in " + LARGE_PIZZA + " slices results in a slice area of " + Math.Round(wholePizzaArea / LARGE_PIZZA, 2) + "\" per slice");
                                Console.Write("\nCut in " + EXTRA_LARGE_PIZZA + " slices results in a slice area of " + Math.Round(wholePizzaArea / EXTRA_LARGE_PIZZA, 2) + "\" per slice");
                            }
                            else if (pizzaDiameter > 24)
                            {
                                Console.Write("Cut in " + SMALL_PIZZA + " slices results in a slice area of " + Math.Round(wholePizzaArea / SMALL_PIZZA, 2) + "\" per slice");
                                Console.Write("\nCut in " + MEDIUM_PIZZA + " slices results in a slice area of " + Math.Round(wholePizzaArea / MEDIUM_PIZZA, 2) + "\" per slice");
                                Console.Write("\nCut in " + LARGE_PIZZA + " slices results in a slice area of " + Math.Round(wholePizzaArea / LARGE_PIZZA, 2) + "\" per slice");
                            }
                            else if (pizzaDiameter > 20)
                            {
                                Console.Write("Cut in " + SMALL_PIZZA + " slices results in a slice area of " + Math.Round(wholePizzaArea / SMALL_PIZZA, 2) + "\" per slice");
                                Console.Write("\nCut in " + MEDIUM_PIZZA + " slices results in a slice area of " + Math.Round(wholePizzaArea / MEDIUM_PIZZA, 2) + "\" per slice");
                            }
                            else if (pizzaDiameter >= 12)
                            {
                                Console.Write("Cut in " + SMALL_PIZZA + " slices results in a slice area of " + Math.Round(wholePizzaArea / SMALL_PIZZA, 2) + "\" per slice");

                            }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.Write("\n\tENTRY ERROR\n\nPizza must have a diameter in the range of 12\" to 36\" inclusive! \n\nPlease try again.");
                        }
                        }
                    }
                    Console.Write("\n\nPlease enter the diameter of your pizza (0 to end program): ");


                } while (pizzaDiameter > 0);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your complete do while loop, so that we can look in to it

Comment: are you taking about this else statement `else
                        {
                            Console.Write("\n\tENTRY ERROR\n\nPizza must have a diameter in the range of 12\" to 36\" inclusive! \n\nPlease try again.");
                        }`

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a problem with your brackets

change your final else to this, should help a bit:

```
                        else if (pizzaDiameter >= 12)
                        {
                            Console.Write("Cut in " + SMALL_PIZZA + " slices results in a slice area of " + Math.Round(wholePizzaArea / SMALL_PIZZA, 2) + "\" per slice");

                        }
                    }//add this bracket here
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write("\n\tENTRY ERROR\n\nPizza must have a diameter in the range of 12\" to 36\" inclusive! \n\nPlease try again.");
                    //} remove this one
                    }
```

Comment: Yes, if the last `else` block would be indented correctly in the original code the error would be more obvious.

Comment: looks like it was indented correctly in the OP. The else is not intended to go with the if else statements above it, but instead the if statement before them, just a simple bracket error.

Comment: My advice is to make use of the Visual Studio IDE's breakpoints to find out where the code steps into! And use Visual Studio features like auto-indent (CTRL+K-D) to make sure your code is well-indented.

Comment: I figured it was something to do with my bracket setup, still trying to get the hang of it. When I implemented the changes suggested above they ended up giving me a bunch of errors, "Error 6 ) expected 89 102 
Error 3 ; expected 82 25 
Error 7 Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'bool' 89 21 PizzaPiLab3
Error 2 Invalid expression term 'else'
Error 8 Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement
Error 4 Syntax error, '(' expected
Error 5 Syntax error, 'while' expected
Error 1 Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

Comment: try removing one of them, after looking closer at the code, it looks like you may have an extra closing bracket that shouldnt be there. I cant tell for sure, since this doesnt look like a complete function